# Too much vertical spacing after `\hline` in `array` environment

Tags: math-mode, vertical-spacing

I have the following equation system:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{flalign*}
  \begin{array}{lllclllr}
   & 2x &-& 9y &+& 5 &=& 0\\
   -& 2x &+& 6y &+& 20 &=& 0\\[2pt]
   \hline\\[-2\baselineskip]
   &&& -15y &-& 15 &=& 0\\
   &&&&& y &=& -1
  \end{array}&&
 \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get rid of the extra space after the `hline`? I just want 2 points of vertical space there, like I have above it.

Removing the line break completely results in the following line being way to close to the `\hline`, and then adding `hspace` has no effect, whatever the magnitude.

**Note.** I am using `flalign*` for a reason. It has to do with the rest of my document.

Comment: Off-topic: You don't appear to be making use of any of the capabilities of the `flalign*` environment. To reduce code clutter, I suggest you replace `\begin{flalign*}` and `\end{flalign*}` with `\[` and `\]`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\\` after `\hline` opens a new row in the table. You can use TeX primitive `\noalign` just after the end of the row (i.e. just after `\\` in LaTeX or `\cr` in the TeX primitive meaning). The parameter of the `\noalign` primitive includes a vertical list. In our case, it is space, line, space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{flalign*}
  \begin{array}{lllclllr}
   & 2x &-& 9y &+& 5 &=& 0\\
   -& 2x &+& 6y &+& 20 &=& 0\\
   \noalign{\kern2pt\hrule\kern3pt}
   &&& -15y &-& 15 &=& 0\\
   &&&&& y &=& -1
  \end{array}&&
 \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a better tool than `\hline`: `\midrule`, which is provided by the `booktabs` package.

If you want to use an `array` environment to typeset sytems of equations, you should set `\arrayrulsep` -- the parameter that contruls the amount of whitespace padding at the column edges -- to `0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}% for \math[lr]lap macros
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \midrule macro
\usepackage{array}    % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{{}}c<{{}} } % for mathbin and mathrel operators

\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{array}{ l rCrCrCr }
      & 2x &-&           9y &+&  5 &=&  0\\
   -( & 2x &+&           6y &+& 20 &=&  0\mathrlap{)}\\
   \midrule
     & & &  \mathllap{-15}y &-& 15 &=&  0\\
     & & &                  & &  y &=& -1
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```